# Ajax autosave function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm currently adding data into db table via Ajax like this: When user pushes button with id #submit_btn it fires following function and posts data. The code of function looks like this.

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function () {
    $("#add_form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataString = $("#add_form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "processor/dbadd.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result, status, xResponse) {
                //do something if ajax call is success
                var message = result.msg;
                var err = result.err;
                if (message != null) {
                    $.notifyBar({ cls: "success", html: message });
                }
                if (err != null) {
                      $.notifyBar({ cls: "error", html:err});
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                //ajax call failed
                alert(e);
            }
        });
    });
```

Is there anyway to modify this code for automatic submission in every 2-3 seconds? (autosave)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there is. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout

Comment: I must set timeout for `$("#submit_btn").click(function () {`?

Comment: No, just for the Ajax call itself. Just be sure to remove the `alert()` from the error callback - otherwise, if the connection is lost, you get dozens of alerts

Comment: No. Use `setTimeout` to submit the form `$("#add_form").submit( ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pleas try this code

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var int = window.setInterval("call();",2000);
            $("#add_form").submit(function (e) {
                  // PLACE YOUR SUBMIT CODE HERE
            });

            $("#submit_btn").click(function () {
                  $('#add_form').submit();
            }); 
    });

    function call(){
        $('#add_form').submit();
    }

    </script>
```

/// NEW ANSWER

```
<script>
    var int;

    $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#add_form").submit(function (e) {
                  // PLACE YOUR SUBMIT CODE HERE
            });

            $("#submit_btn").click(function () {
                  int = window.clearInterval(int)
                  int = window.setInterval("call();",3000);
            }); 
    });

    function call(){
        $('#add_form').submit();
    }

</script>
```

///THIRD ANSWER

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#add_form").submit(function (e) {
                  // PLACE YOUR SUBMIT CODE HERE
              });

             $("#submit_btn").click(function () {
                   int = window.setInterval("call();",3000);
                   $(this).attr({'disabled':'disabled'});
                   $(':input#autosave').attr({'disabled':'disabled'});
            }); 

            $(':input#autosave').click(function(){
                if($(this).is(':checked')){
                    $(':input#submit_btn').attr({'value':'Save & exit'});
                }
                else{
                    $(':input#submit_btn').attr({'value':'Save'});
                }
            });
    });

    function call(){
        $('#add_form').submit();
    }
</script>


</head>

<body>
<form id="add_form" action="" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" id="autosave" value="1"/>
<input id="submit_btn" type="submit" name="save" value="Save"/>

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: you can change 2000 with any of other milisecond as your requirement.

Comment: @The Coder here your form will get submitted after every 2 second autometically. So if you want to stop the autosubmit then you need to use clearInterval() function to stop the function calling.

Comment: Now the problem is, i want to start autosubmit only if user pushed submit first time

Comment: Yes you can do this cut the window.setInterval() from top and paste it inside your $("#submit_btn").click(function () {// function

Comment: just replace this with older ones - $("#submit_btn").click(function () {
                  var int = window.setInterval("call();",2000);

 });

Comment: i want to insert data in every 3 sec. but make button available still. now the problem is. when user pushes the button for second, third time. new intervals are appearing

Comment: @TheCoder Then you need to use clearInterval(int); This will clear out the existing interval. also var int is defined inside the document so please remove this var from document and place it just after your <script> tag. I also want to mention that you have to try  $("#submit_btn").click(function () {//clearInterval(int); or window.clearInterval(int); $('#add_form').submit();
            });

Comment: please modify your solution. i can't understand.

Comment: can we continue discussion via skype or gtalk, or anything else?

Comment: My ajax function doesn't send data into db table, it works only when i click the button

Comment: @TheCoder Please let me verify this.

Comment: please give me your IM.I wanna talk to you

Comment: @TheCoder Is this ok with you if after first click disabling the submit button so the interval won't conflict with other interval. Basically after clicking on button will initiate the interval meanwhile disabling the button so for the next time no one click on the button. If this sounds good to you or can you adopt this strategy? (which i can give immediately) Or you need other solution. Feel free to discuss your requirement here.

Comment: http://pastie.org/2637131 Please take a look at my full code. As you see RSV function validates the form. My main problem is RSV validates the form onlclick, and js code posts data directly to php without checking if validation returned false value. How to fix that problem? And second problem is, can we do something like this: Put autosave checkbox near the "submit" button and if autosave checked, then change button into "save and exit" and if not checked leave it as it is: "save"

Comment: you mean to say that form should be submitted when it passes the validation every time when the form submission is performed.

Comment: no. only 1 time. when user clicks for the first time it should pass validation, if validation returned true then, post via ajax. and fire post lets say in every 30 sec. Validation passes if function 'myOnComplete()' returns true

Comment: @TheCoder See my new answer. Make changes according to your need. Does it code near to your requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `setTimeout`, which you have to set over and over again, consider using `setInterval`, which needs to be called only once.

Comment: please modify given code. i'm newbie to js. I don't understand how code must look like

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to put the content of `$('#add_form')` in a separate function, say, `submt()` and call submit on `setTimeout` or if the `$('#submit_btn')` is clicked.

Comment: 1) please modify given code. i'm newbie to js. 2) All theese functions will be within `$(document).ready(function () {`?